# Joining two table based on few conditions which results in some TOP data from two tables

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I am trying to Create a SQL View by joining two SQL tables and return the latest value from second table and all the rows from first table similar to left join along with the TOP 1 record from table2 where there is no match in table 1 grouped by product,grade,term

My problem can be clearly explained with the below example.

**Table1**

```
Id  Product Grade Term Bid Offer 
100 ABC       A   Q1   10  20
101 ABC       A   Q1   5   25
102 XYZ       A   Q2   25  30
103 XYZ       B   Q2   20  30
```

**Table2**

```
Id Product Grade Term TradeValue
1  ABC     A     Q1     100
2  ABC     A     Q1     95    
3  XYZ     B     Q2     100
4  PQR     C     Q2     100
5  PQR     C     Q2     200
```

In the above data I want to join `Table1` and `Table2` when ever the columns `Product,Grade and Term` from both the tables are equal and return all the rows from `Table1` while joining the latest Value of the column `TradeValue` from `Table2` to the first record of the match and making `TradeValue as NULL` for other rows of the resultant View and the resultant View should have the `Id` of `Table2` as `LTID` and it also should return TOP 1 row from Table 2 where Product,Grade and Term are not equal grouping by Product,Grade and Term

So the resultant SQL View should be

**RESULT**

```
   Id  Product Grade Term Bid Offer TradeValue LTID
   100  ABC       A   Q1   10   20    100         2
   101  ABC       A   Q1   5    25    NULL       NULL
   102  XYZ       A   Q2   25   30    NULL       NULL
   103  XYZ       B   Q2   20   30    100         3
   104  PQR       C   Q2   NULL NULL  200         5
```

I tried using the following query

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8884/7

As we can see latest value of `TradeValue` being assigned to all matching rows in `Table1` and also I was not able to return the TOP 1 row  from Table2 where a match was not found

**May I know a better way to deal with this?**

Comment: Where did you get 104  PQR from?

Comment: I didn't get that but I just want to create a custom id for that and 104 is in my expected result

Comment: You take the lowest Value of the column TradeValue from Table2, but it's 95, for example per ABC, A, Q1

Comment: @Dev, correct RESULT from sample tables 1, 2. Other way what is the purpose of providing incorrect result for sample data?

Comment: @Alex sorry for the confusion. I meant to say the latest value not the lowest

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Well I included the results I got from my query

Comment: @Dev, no can you provide expected result for provided sample Table 1 and Table2?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri RESULT is the expected results

Comment: @Dev, man you say `return only the latest value from second table and all the rows from first table`. Doesn't it mean that you want return 4 rows(because you have 4 rows in Table1) and corresponding latest values from table2? Then how do you get 5 rows in Result???

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri sorry for the confusion but going deep into the question I explained what I exactly wanted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69836/discussion-between-giorgi-nakeuri-and-dev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.Product) as ID,d.*,t1.Bid,t1.Offer,t2.LastTradeValue,t2.ID AS LTID 
FROM
(
  SELECT Product,Grade,Term
  FROM Table1
  UNION 
  SELECT Product,Grade,Term
  FROM Table2 
) d
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON d.Product=t1.Product AND d.Grade=t1.Grade AND d.Term=t1.Term
OUTER APPLY 
(
  SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table2 t2 WHERE d.Product=t2.Product AND d.Grade=t2.Grade AND d.Term=t2.Term
  ORDER BY t2.ID DESC
) t2
```

Comment: Thanks and how do I add an ID to the results it can be 1,2,3 and so on

Comment: If those ID is just an incremental number you could add it as ROW_NUMBER() to resultset

Comment: I just figured out that if Table2 is empty it doesn't return any rows as in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c34e/1

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Sql Server 2012 let me suggest the following:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE
    (
      Id INT ,
      Product CHAR(3) ,
      Grade CHAR(1) ,
      Term CHAR(2) ,
      Bid INT ,
      Offer INT
    )
DECLARE @t2 TABLE
    (
      Id INT ,
      Product CHAR(3) ,
      Grade CHAR(1) ,
      Term CHAR(2) ,
      TradeValue INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t1
VALUES  ( 100, 'ABC', 'A', 'Q1', 10, 20 ),
        ( 101, 'ABC', 'A', 'Q1', 5, 25 ),
        ( 102, 'XYZ', 'A', 'Q2', 25, 30 ),
        ( 103, 'XYZ', 'B', 'Q2', 20, 30 )

INSERT  INTO @t2
VALUES  ( 1, 'ABC', 'A', 'Q1', 100 ),
        ( 2, 'ABC', 'A', 'Q1', 95 ),
        ( 3, 'XYZ', 'B', 'Q2', 100 ),
        ( 4, 'PQR', 'C', 'Q2', 100 ),
        ( 5, 'PQR', 'C', 'Q2', 200 ),
        ( 6, 'TTT', 'C', 'Q2', 200 ),
        ( 7, 'TTT', 'C', 'Q2', 201 ),
        ( 8, 'JJJ', 'C', 'Q2', 500 );

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   t1.Id AS t1Id ,
                        t1.Product AS t1Product ,
                        t1.Grade AS t1Grade ,
                        t1.Term AS t1Term ,
                        t1.Bid AS t1Bid ,
                        t1.Offer AS t1Offer ,
                        IIF(t1.ID IS NULL, t1.Id, t2.Id) AS ordert2Id ,
                        t2.Id AS t2Id ,
                        t2.Product AS t2Product ,
                        t2.Grade AS t2Grade ,
                        t2.Term AS t2Term ,
                        t2.TradeValue AS t2TradeValue
               FROM     @t2 t2
                        FULL JOIN @t1 t1 ON t2.Product = t1.Product
                                            AND t2.Grade = t1.Grade
                                            AND t2.Term = t1.Term
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t2Product, t2Grade, t2Term, t1Id ORDER BY ordert2Id ) AS rn1 ,
                        RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY t2Product, t2Grade, t2Term ORDER BY t1Id ) AS rn2 ,
                        LAST_VALUE(t2TradeValue) OVER ( PARTITION BY t2Product, t2Grade, t2Term ORDER BY ordert2Id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS TradeValue ,
                        LAST_VALUE(t2Id) OVER ( PARTITION BY t2Product, t2Grade, t2Term ORDER BY t2Id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS TradeId
               FROM     cte
             )
    SELECT  t1Id AS ID ,
            ISNULL(t1Product, t2Product) AS Product ,
            ISNULL(t1Grade, t2Grade) AS Product ,
            ISNULL(t1Term, t2Term) AS Product ,
            t1Bid AS Bid ,
            t1Offer AS Offer,
            IIF(rn2 = 1, TradeValue, NULL) AS TradeValue,
            IIF(rn2 = 1, TradeId, NULL) AS LTID

    FROM    cte2
    WHERE   rn1 = 1
```

Output:

```
ID   Product    Product Product Bid  Offer  TradeValue  LTID
NULL PQR        C       Q2      NULL NULL   200         5
100  ABC        A       Q1      10   20     95          2
101  ABC        A       Q1      5    25     NULL        NULL
102  XYZ        A       Q2      25   30     NULL        NULL
103  XYZ        B       Q2      20   30     100         3
```

Comment: Thanks but what about the values for Product TTT and JJJ in t2

Comment: I've edited answer several times, because fitst attemps returened incorrect data on different test data. And forgot to update output. You can execute statement and see that ttt and jjj are also included.